# If a commutative ring is connected, then its reduced ring is connected.

Tags: commutative-algebra, alternative-proof, nilpotence, idempotents

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit and $N$ its nilradical. If $R$ is connected then $R/N$ is also connected; the quotient map induces a homeomorphism between the spectra. I'd like to see a more hands-on proof, but I'm unable to make it work. That is to say, I'd like to show that if $e^2-e\in N$ for some $e\in R$, then $e\in N$ or $e-1\in N$. After scribbling full quite a couple of pages going around in circles, any idea is welcome.

Comment: Take the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. This ring is connected, as $2^2 = 0$ and $3^2 = 1$, so we have no non-trivial idempotents. However, taking $e = 3$ we have $e^2 - e = 2 \in N$, but $e^2-e \neq 0$. So you should add that not only $e^2-e \in N$ but also $e,e-1 \not \in N$.

Answer (score 4):

See http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~lee/algebra/idempotent.pdf, but I'll repeat the argument here.

Suppose $e-e^2\in N$ and set $f=1-e$. Then $e^kf^k=0$, for some $k\ge1$.

Note that $e^k+N=e+N$ and $f^k+N=f+N$, so we can replace $e$ and $f$ with $e^k$ and $f^k$, so now $ef=0$.

Set $x=1-e-f\in N$; then $x^l=0$, for some $l\ge1$. Hence $1-x$ as the inverse $u=1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{l-1}$. Also $u-1\in N$ and
$$
ue+N=e+N,\qquad uf+N=f+N
$$
so we can replace $e$ and $f$ by $ue$ and $uf$.

Now $e+f=1$. So
$$
e=e(e+f)=e^2+ef=e^2
$$

Comment: Your sketch of the argument is very succinct, but still crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that every idempotent modulo $N$ can be lifted to an idempotent of $R$.  Thus, if $R$ has no non trivial idempotent, then $R/N$ also has no non trivial idempotent. (See Anderson's "Rings and Categories of modules")

Comment: @Servaes It means that if $(r+I)^2=r+I$, then there exists an $e\in R$ such that $e^2=e$ and $e+I=r+I$. That is, every idempotent in the quotient $R/I$ has a coset representative that is idempotent in the ring $R$.

Comment: @Servaes The fact referenced here is precisely the one cited in the other solution, and you already have a sketch in the other solution anyway. To the two downvoters: maybe you have a case for not upvoting, but I think these downvotes are inappropriately used. The answer *is* useful and correct, and only differs from the other one in how many details are included.

Comment: @rschwieb I was the other downvoter. The original post asked explicitly for a "hands-on proof", and this answer doesn't give one. Instead, it just restates the problem and gives an imprecise reference. Not to mention two major typos in a two sentence answer (see the edits by the OP and myself)...

Comment: @AlexKruckman *shrug* To me, everything you're saying describes an answer that deserves no votes either up or down. It's not that big of a deal, but I just want everyone to reality check here that in fact both answers refer to identical solutions (typos aside), but one answer simply typed out the solution from a reference (and I agree that would warrant upvotes.)

Comment: @Servaes Well... many problems are made much easier by restatement (as long as it is nontrivial.) You have a point that this solution does nothing different than the first one: I had not realized that this was made hours after the first one. Still, I would think that would mean *no upvotes* rather than downvotes. I guess I prefer a "negative-neutral-positive" viewpoint for voting rather than a binary "negative-positive" (doesn'tdoeverything/doesdoevertying) viewpoint.

Comment: @rschwieb I vote down answers that I see as poor quality, and I think the answerer has a responsibility to (1) write clearly and to (2) read the question carefully enough to know what kind of answer will be helpful. I would not have downvoted if the Servaes had not made clear what kind of answer they were looking for by writing "hands-on". Obviously, different people have different voting philosophies, and the comments are probably not the best place to discuss them.